# Clickatell - Whatsapp integration

Tags: clickatell

I'm trying to send a test message using Whatsapp and I'm getting this error message:

`"error":{"code":27,"description":"Recipient not available on channel."}`

I did find the error message here (https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/one-api-error-messages/) but it does not give more details as to what's wrong.

Below is my curl request.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: (hidden)" -d '{"messages": [{ "channel": "whatsapp", "to": "1xxxxxxxxxx", "content": "Test WhatsApp Message Text", "From": "1xxxxxxxxxx"}]}' -s https://platform.clickatell.com/v1/message
```

Can anyone give me more insight into this error message?

Answer (score 2):

As per their documentation https://media.clickatell.com/OnlineBrochures/WhatsApp%20REST%20API%20%20Technical%20Documentation%20V4.8.pdf

POST /wa/messages

Content-Type: application/json

Authorization: MC2 integration API KEY

JSON Request

```
{
 "messages": [
 {
 "to": "27999000001",
 "content": "Here is an example message",
 "clientMessageId": "2993b6b548000a80989a20549e7558a5"
 }
 ]
}
```

Comment: That's not the same API the OP is referring to. OP is trying to use their ["One API"](https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/one-api-send-plain-text-message/).

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the channel 'Whatsapp' instead of 'whatsapp', as described in the Clickatell docs.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. 1. WhatsApp -> Whatsapp Numbers -> Manage Integrations - on their site shows an example and it's in lowercase. 2. I did try it with uppercase and it does not work.